# How clean old segments from compacted log in Kafka 0.8.2

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-kafka

I know that in new Kafka versions we have new retention policy option - compaction of log which delete old version of messages with same keys. But after long time we will get too many compacted log segments with old messages. How can we clean this compacted log automatically?

**UDPATE**:

I should clarify that we need compact log and way to clean up old messages this in those time.
I found discussion for same problem here http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/14bv6gaz0t/kafka-0-8-2-log-cleaner
but not found how we can manually issue thomstone markers for message and have not any idea this.

Comment: Just for clarification, you're asking how to clean up a log that has already been compacted?

Comment: Yes, we will have latest versions of messages with unique keys but this sequence can grow to very big size.  I hope that exist any way to compact recent log segments and delete oldest, for example. Or maybe other way to mark messages to delete. Sorry for my bad english, but I really want understand this technology.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but I thought I'd give the latest update on the matter. There is a feature (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4015) which is already resolved and is scheduled for the 0.10.1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way to lower the size of your Kafka Log would be through the log retention configuration settings.

```
log.retention.{ms,minutes,hours}
log.retention.bytes
```

> Also note that if both log.retention.hours and log.retention.bytes are both set we delete a segment when either limit is exceeded.

Those two dictate when logs are deleted in Kafka. The log.retention.bytes defaults to -1, and I'm pretty sure leaving it to -1 allows only the time config to solely determine when a log gets deleted.

Log retention and compaction work separately from each other. Using retention, logs can be deleted after a certain time or size even with log compaction on. So if you theoretically have a 100Mb log limit, and set the your log.retention.bytes=104857600 (100Mb). Kafka will compact your log until it reaches 100Mb in size, and then will delete the necessary messages (oldest first) until the log is under 100Mb in size.

EDIT:

It turns out that log retention and compaction are mutually exclusive based on this [link](http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/14bv6gaz0t/kafka-0-8-2-log-cleaner) provided by mechanikos. Though it seems odd that Kafka is designed so a log will grow indefinitely with no capability of ever deleting old log messages.

Comment: But official doc says "This configuration controls the maximum size a log can grow to before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the "delete" retention policy. By default there is no size limit only a time limit." for log.retention.ms for example. It will work if we set "delete" option, but for compaction we need set "compact"

Comment: What you're quoting comes from the Topic-level configuration, correct? I was basing my answer on the Broker Configs. Setting the broker config, log.cleaner.enable=true, and log.retention.ms=10000, messages were deleted from the Kafka topic after their time expired. (I ran a sample topic just to double check) I don't exactly know how the Topic-level configurations interact with the broker-level configuration at the moment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your work and answers, I will try test your advice at work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this don't work with log compaction. Maybe I didn't understand your first comment. I need working compaction log and delete oldest messages.
Topic-level config just override broker-level settings. 
Docs says that about retention policy " This can take either the value delete or compact. If delete is set, log segments will be deleted when they reach the size or time limits set. If compact is set log compaction will be used to clean out obsolete records." . Its look like log retention and compaction don`t work separately

Comment: I read through the link you provided, seems like I was wrong in my initial answer. Can you edit your question and put the retention and compaction related broker and topic level configuration values so I or anyone else reading this question can know more about your current configuration.