# How long are compacted logs kept in Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka. I have been reading about the Compaction clean up policy. I am particularly interested in this because I want to use this policy on topics which are used to sync different data stores to achieve eventual consistency.

I see that there is a `delete.retention.ms` option available for me to use. But this only applies to the "delete" tombstones/payloads. I understand that this option limits the time by which I can have a consumer re-run after a failure to look at records from `offset=0`. However, I never hard delete anything in my system. In other words, I am never going to have "delete" tombstones/payloads.

Since I am never going to have delete tombstones, I want to know how long Kafka will keep the compacted log?

NOTE: I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632362/how-clean-old-segments-from-compacted-log-in-kafka-0-8-2) question which lead me to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4015) issue. This does not answer what I need to know or this is not something I can use to set a limit on how long the compacted log lives. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use log compaction (and not log retention) Kafka will keep the latest entry for each key *forever* (until you delete the whole key with an explicit tombstone message `<key:null>`).

Comment: As a follow up question, what are some good ways to manage the size of that data?

Comment: The size of you topic depend (using log compaction) depends on two factor: (1) the number of distinct key (this is basically a lower bound of the log size) and (2) how eagerly log clean up gets triggered, in combination with you input/update write. The log clean up interval can be configured.

Answer (score 1):

As per [KIP-71](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist), now you can apply the policy:

```
"compact,delete"
```

which will apply both, each one with their thresholds.